# Template argument deduction from inherited type

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++14

I want a setup like the following:

```
template <typename T> class a {};

class b : public a<int> {};

template <typename T>
void do_foo(std::unique_ptr<a<T>> foo)
{
    // Do something with foo
}

int main()
{
    do_foo(std::make_unique<b>());
}
```

This fails to compile with a note saying `template argument deduction/substitution failed` and `mismatched types 'a<T>' and 'b'`.  It's pretty self-explanatory.  I can help the compiler along by writing `do_foo<int>(std::make_unique<b>());`, but then I'm repeating myself by writing `int` twice.

Is there a way to get the compiler to deduce the template parameter in this case? And what would you call this behaviour?  I tried searching for things like "template type deduction for inherited type", "polymorphic template deduction" etc.

Comment: Yeah, it would work with a raw pointer/reference. But the unique_ptr makes this a non-starter.

Comment: Not keen to use a raw pointer - I'd rather repeat myself!

Comment: Does `do_foo` really need to take ownership of the pointer?  If not, take by reference, `void do_foo(const a<T>& var)` and then dereference the pointer at the call site.

Comment: @NathanOliver Changing it wouldn't be worth the effort. I'm mostly just interested in what people more knowledgeable than me have to say.

Comment: There's lots of things to say. If you have more arguments, this one can be made into a non-deduced context. Or you can just add another overload. And probably other things I can't recall. But there isn't enough in this post for anyone to say what is the best suggestion.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I've reworded the question.  Even if it makes the answer a simple 'no', it's what I care about in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the compiler to deduce the template parameter in this case?

No. Not in C++14 (or even C++20).

> And what would you call this behaviour?

Standard compliant. To be specific, this paragraph applies:

> **[temp.deduct.call]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.deduct.call#4) In general, the deduction process attempts to find template
> argument values that will make the deduced `A` identical to `A` (after
> the type `A` is transformed as described above). However, there are
> three cases that allow a difference:
>
> - If the original `P` is a reference type, the deduced `A` (i.e., the type referred to by the reference) can be more cv-qualified than the
>   transformed `A`.
> - The transformed `A` can be another pointer or pointer to member type that can be converted to the deduced `A` via a qualification
>   conversion ([conv.qual]).
> - If `P` is a class and `P` has the form *simple-template-id*, then the transformed `A` can be a derived class of the deduced `A`.
>   Likewise, if `P` is a pointer to a class of the form
>   *simple-template-id*, the transformed `A` can be a pointer to a derived class pointed to by the deduced `A`.

This is an exhaustive list of cases where a template argument can be validly deduced from a function argument even if it doesn't match the pattern of the function parameter *exactly*. The first and second bullets deal with things like

```
template<class A1> void func(A1&){}
template<class A2> void func(A2*){}

int main() {
    const int i = 1;
    func(i); // A1 = const int
    func(&i); // A2 = const int
}
```

The third bullet is the one that is closest to our case. A class derived from a template specialization can be used to deduce a template parameter pertaining to its base. Why doesn't it work in your case? Because the function template parameter is `unique_ptr<a<T>>` and the argument you call it with is `unique_ptr<b>`. The `unique_ptr` specializations are not *themselves* related by inheritance. So they don't match the bullet, and deduction fails.

But it doesn't mean that a wrapper like `unique_ptr` prevents template argument deduction entirely. For instance:

```
template <typename> struct A {};
struct B : A<int> {};

template<typename> struct wrapper{};
template<> struct wrapper<B> : wrapper<A<int>> {};

template<typename T>
void do_smth(wrapper<A<T>>) {}

int main() {
    do_smth(wrapper<B>{});
}
```

In this case, `wrapper<B>` derives from `wrapper<A<int>>`. So the third bullet is applicable. And by the complex (and recursive) process of template argument deduction, it allows `B` to match `A<T>` and deduce `T = int`.

**TL;DR**: `unique_ptr<T>` specializations cannot replicate the behavior of raw pointers. They don't inherit from the specializations of `unique_ptr` over `T`'s bases. Maybe if reflection ever comes to C++, we'll be able to meta-program a smart pointer that *does* behave that way.

Answer (score 1):

As workaround, you might add overload:

```
template <typename T>
void do_foo_impl(a<T>* foo)
{
    return do_foo(std::unique_ptr<a<T>>(foo));
}

template <typename T>
auto do_foo(std::unique_ptr<T> foo) -> decltype(do_foo_impl(foo.release()))
{
    do_foo_impl(foo.release());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95d25cd63f156215)

Comment: The second `do_foo` can be made to accept `std::unique_ptr<T>`, no? I think it's still less in partial ordering than `std::unique_ptr<a<T>>`. That will obviate the the need for expression SFINAE in the trailing return type. And the overload could then just be made to return `decltype(auto)`. Would make the code look a bit more DRY. Of course, if the OP has no other overloads. Otherwise the SFINAE may be preferable.

Comment: Changed to `std::unique_ptr<T>`, I kept the SFINAE for the `b*` -> `a<U>*` conversion check.