# Variadic Template deduction failed

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am trying to make a pipeline of operations type-safe.  The code below is greatly simplified, but I believe it has the essential parts.

I have tried most combinations and orders of the variadic packs, but I don't believe that to be the problem.
I suspect the issue is 1) of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts, but the method shown there to work around it doesn't work here.

I am open to solutions that simply avoid the problem entirely, so long as the chain of operations is properly type-checked, and the final Pipeline has the correct Op<> type.

```cpp
enum DType {
  INT,
  FLOAT,
  DOUBLE,
};

template<DType InputT, DType OutputT>
class Op: public BaseOp {// Do stuff 
};

template<DType InputT, DType OutputT>
class Pipeline:Op<InputT, OutputT> {
vector<Ptr<BaseOp>> pipeline_stages;
public:
  Pipeline(Ptr<OP<InputT, OutputT>> stage) {
    //add to pipeline_stages 
  };
  
  template<DType TempOutputT, class... Stages>
  Pipeline(Ptr<Op<InputT, TempOutputT>> stage, Stages... stages):Pipeline(stage, Pipeline<TempOutputT, OutputT>(stages...)) {}

  template<DType OldOutputT>
  Pipeline(Ptr<Op<InputT,OldOutputT>> stage, Pipeline<OldOutputT,OutputT> other) {
    //Insert stages to vec
  };

  //Do all the Pipeline and Op stuff
};

// Ideally, this would work with auto mypipe.
Pipeline<DType::INT, DType::FLOAT> mypipe(
  make_ptr<CovertOp<DType::INT, DType::FLOAT>>(),
  make_ptr<FloatOp1>(),
  make_ptr<FloatOp2>(param)
  );
```

Comment: Can you solve your problem using [`std::ranges`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) or Eric Niebler's [range v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library to construct the pipeline?

Comment: I sincerely doubt it.  Ranges are, in all cases I've seen, a single type.  It might be a compound type, but there's no provision for an iterator to change types.

Comment: Hmmm, I've used ranges to convert from double to string to pair to vectors.

Comment: True, but that is not the problem.  The problem is to have a series of operations composed, type-checked, and stored as a single "super operation".  

You can take your range<string> and use range::transform to range<pair> no problem.  But what I need is equivalent to a lot of range::transform calls all chained together, and make sure they work. Only then will any actual data be used.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a complicated version of [Template argument deduction from inherited type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66356320/template-argument-deduction-from-inherited-type)

In short: The Ptrs don't have the same inheritance tree as the operations, so it can't deduce that `Ptr<ConvertOp<INT,FLOAT>>` is related to `Ptr<Op<INT,FLOAT>>` in the template.